# Restart required message for real?

Tags: lumia-950, lumia

My Lumia 950 keeps getting this message:

"Restart required: Your phone's settings or the SIM card have changed.  Restart your phone to complete the installation."

Is this for real?

Answer (score 2):

This can happen as your carrier can push settings for your SIM card to your phone. 
Just do the restart, no worries.